# Simple property formatting

Tags: .net, vb.net

In a VB.Net class, I have an method that replaces all square brackets `[]` in certain properties by normal brackets `()`.

*Edit:
The program allows users to write custom calculations, such as `[3-(6-2)]`. Being able to use two kinds of brackets makes things easier for them, but when processing the calculation, it's easier to have the same brackets everywhere.*

The code is really redundant:

```
Public Sub removeBadBrackets()
    ValueCalc = Replace(Replace(ValueCalc, "[", "("), "]", ")")
    TargetCalc = Replace(Replace(TargetCalc, "[", "("), "]", ")")
    LLLCalc = Replace(Replace(LLLCalc, "[", "("), "]", ")")
    LLCalc = Replace(Replace(LLCalc, "[", "("), "]", ")")
    LCalc = Replace(Replace(LCalc, "[", "("), "]", ")")
    HCalc = Replace(Replace(HCalc, "[", "("), "]", ")")
    HHCalc = Replace(Replace(HHCalc, "[", "("), "]", ")")
    HHHCalc = Replace(Replace(HHHCalc, "[", "("), "]", ")")
End Sub
```

I think this could be done in a more efficient way, and I'd like to learn how.

Side note:

- Those properties are not the only one of the object.
- They are in the same region (although I am not sure regions can be used for anything else than my own convenience).

Thank you for your help improving this.

Comment: Any chance you could comment on why you want to do that? Maybe then there might be a totally different answer

Comment: I edited the main post

Comment: Been a while since I did VB.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods

Answer (score 5):

My VB.NET is incredibly rusty but you should write a separate function:

```
Public Shared Sub ReplaceBracketsWithParentheses(ByRef text As String)
    text = Replace(Replace(text, "[", "("), "]", ")")
End Sub
```

Calling code will then simply be:

```
Public Sub removeBadBrackets()
    ReplaceBracketsWithParentheses(ValueCalc)
    ...
End Sub
```

Note that if you have to replace more than few substrings then a fluid approach may be more readable:

```
Public Shared Sub ReplaceBracketsWithParentheses(ByRef text As String)
    text = text.Replace("[", "(") _
               .Replace("]", ")") _
               .Replace("{", "(") _
               .Replace("}", "]")
End Sub
```

---

If you're translating some sort of mathematical expressions (but not only!) you may also consider to use a `Regex`.

One word about naming: I don't know the domain you're using this code but to me `LLLCalc`, `LLCalc` and so on are not descriptive names (and, anyway, acronyms should be cased PascalCase like `LllCalc`, the same is true for `removeBadBrackets()`).

Comment: I think vb still requires an `_` and the end of a line when you multiline statements

Comment: @Icepickle you're right! Rusty and dusty...

Comment: I agree with the suggestions, but I'm not a big fan of `ByRef` statements. Vb.net does support extension modules, maybe this might be a more appropariate approach but I'm unsure as long as I don't know why the OP wants to do it :)

Comment: At first sight I thought it's to _translate_ mathematical expressions (with parentheses, square brackets and curly brackets...) into parser friendly expressions (for example to use them in a parser like NCalc). Maybe a `Regex` may do better and faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A word on pascalCase, in this context.
As guessed, it is to be used in NCalc, and it's a value, along with limits, LowLowLow, LowLow, Low, High, HighHigh and HighHighHigh.

In such a case where the three letters have the exact same meaning, and the information is contained in their repetition, would it be OK to break the rule?

Comment: It's always _OK_ to break the rules because they're just...guidelines and conventions (not to mention that convention about acronyms isn't so strictly followed). In general I try to follow this convention because I think it makes names easier to read and it favors consistency (`CORBAAAAForBBB` looks pretty weird). But, well, it's such small detail that. One note about NCalc: be careful to blindly replace [ and ], they're used also to delimit identifiers like in `[current value] > [maximum value]` and it may be an handy syntax to keep variables name clear.